# colored scratched out entries in a Table

Tags: tables, color, ulem

I have a weird problem: If I put a scratched out entry (using package ulem) in a table everything ist fine. But if I color that entry it slips down a little bit. 
Does anyone know why?
Here an example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper,final,titlepage,openany]{amsbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{4cm}p{4cm}p{4cm}}
 bla& bla  &bla\\\hline

 bla &{\color{red}{ \sout{bla}}} & bla\\

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `\textcolor` instead, then it works. Note that `\color{<colorname>}` is a switch that turns on coloring for the following text, so you don't need the braces around `\sout{bla}`. `\textcolor` on the other hand has a second argument that is the text to be colored.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper,final,titlepage,openany]{amsbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{4cm}p{4cm}p{4cm}}
 bla& bla  &bla\\\hline
 bla &\textcolor{red}{\sout{bla}} & bla\\
 bla &\color{red} \sout{bla} & bla\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]